# Merge objects class date in one object

Tags: r, date

I create two objects class date.You can see this objects below:

```
DATE_MATRIX<-seq.Date(as.Date("2014-01-01"), as.Date("2014-03-03"), by = "day")
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "English")
DATE_MATRIX1<-weekdays(DATE_MATRIX)
```

So my intention is to merge in one object and to get table like this.This table is only small example

```
 Date          Weekdays    
-------------------------------       
2014-01-01     Wednesday
2014-01-02     Thursday
2014-01-03     Friday
```

I try this code and results are not as I want them to be, because Date and Weekdays are merged together.

```
DATE_MATRIX_FINAL<-paste(DATE_MATRIX,DATE_MATRIX1)

   " 2014-01-01 Wednesday"
   " 2014-01-02 Thursday"
   " 2014-01-03 Friday"
```

So can anybody help how to solve this problem ?

Comment: Do you want to convert the vector to dataframes? `data.frame(Date = DATE_MATRIX, Weekdays = DATE_MATRIX1)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a `data.frame`/`tibble` object from the vectors

```
data.frame(Date = DATE_MATRIX, Weekdays = DATE_MATRIX1)

#         Date  Weekdays
#1  2014-01-01 Wednesday
#2  2014-01-02  Thursday
#3  2014-01-03    Friday
#4  2014-01-04  Saturday
#5  2014-01-05    Sunday
#....
```

Or

```
dplyr::tibble(Date = DATE_MATRIX, Weekdays = DATE_MATRIX1)
```